# How to retrieve the last array of characters before a specific string

Tags: javascript

`row1: 10016/Documents/folder1/abc.pdf`

`row2: 10016-10017/10017/Documents/folder1/folder2/xyz.pdf`

I'm trying to retrieve the string before /Documents but if there is any / before, I need to retrieve the string after that

In row 1, I need to retrieve 10016

In row 2, I need to retrieve 10017

I tried

```
var output = filepath.split("/").slice(0,1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split by `/Documents/` then split that by `/` and get the final element:

```js
const row1 = "10016/Documents/folder1/abc.pdf";
const row2 = "10016-10017/10017/Documents/folder1/folder2/xyz.pdf";

let docs = row1.split("/Documents/")[0];
let nums = docs.split("/");
nums = nums[nums.length - 1];

console.log(nums);

docs = row2.split("/Documents/")[0];
nums = docs.split("/");
nums = nums[nums.length - 1];

console.log(nums);
```

This works for both `row1` and `row2` as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

You can split by '/Documents/', try this:

```js
let str = '10016/Documents/abc.pdf';

console.log(str.split('/Documents/')[0])
```

Comment: for row 2 it is retrieving 10016-10017/10017, while I'm looking to o/p just 10017

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expression to get this

```
([a-z\d]+)\/Documents
```

Explaining the regular expression

- Capture everything which contains one or more occurrences (`+`) occurrence of either an alphabet `(a-z)` or digit `(/d)`
- Also make sure this set of characters are right before a `/Documents` phrase

```js
    let result = RegExp(/([a-z\d]+)\/Documents/).exec('10016/Documents/abc.pdf');
    if (result) { console.log(result[1]) }

    result = RegExp(/([a-z\d]+)\/Documents/).exec('10016-10017/10017/Documents/xyz.pdf');
    if (result) { console.log(result[1]) }
```